# Exchange 2010 SP1 upgrade prerequisite checks fail for KB979744, but update fails as Not Applicable

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, prerequisites

I'm trying to install the SP1 update to an RTM Exchange 2010 box.  The Client Access Role Prerequisites are failing, complaining that KB979744 isn't installed.

I downloaded the update and tried to install it, however it will not install complaining that 'The update does not apply to your system'.

A discussion on TechNet indicates that I need .NET 2.0 or 3.5 installed (both are).  Aside from that I've been unable to find anything helpful.

Hopefully someone has encountered this and knows how to get around it, don't really want to use up a support call on this.

**Edit**:

This is on a 64-bit edition of Windows Server 2008 Datacenter (without Hyper-V) SP2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error `The update does not apply to your system` means you already have the update installed, or you are installing a version of the patch for a different Operating System than the one you are running (it might also mean you're trying to install the 32-bit version, but I'm not 100% on that).

Just to double check, you want [code.msdn.com](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB979744/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3993) and you want the file **Windows6.0-KB979744-x64.msu (CBS: Vista/Win2K8)**.

If you definitely are installing the right update, check out the tail end of `C:\Windows\WindowsUpdate.log` to see if that gives you any more insight. If you need help trying to decipher it, please edit your original post to include the relevant tail end of the file.

Comment: Wow am I embarrassed.  I downloaded the x86 version of it (only it, the other updates I needed were all x64).  Took someone to actually tell me to check to make me check heh.  Downloaded the x64 and it has installed fine.

Comment: No worries - I've done it before, and no doubt I'll do it again some day! Good luck with the Exchange upgrade - mine went without a hitch (it just took ages to install the cumulative update afterwards). If you have any problems, just post another question on Server Fault :-)

Comment: Yup went smoothly - a nice change.  After about 45 minutes of installation it was all done.  Didn't prompt for a reboot either, which was nice. Mail was flowing again and services were up, but restarted anyway :)